# Sum frequency generation and optical rectification

Tags: optics, spectroscopy, non-linear-optics

What is the difference between sum frequency generation and optical rectification if frequency mixing is at the core of both the processes. Is one of these processes a subtype of order ?

Answer (score 0):

Optical rectification is the result of a nonlinear dielectric medium characterized by having an amplitude $\hat E$ dependent polarization  $$\mathcal P(\mathcal {\hat {E}}) = \chi^{(1)} \mathcal {\hat {E}} + \chi^{(2)} \mathcal {\hat {E}}^2  + ....$$
in which an EM wave of electric field intensity $E(t) = {\hat {E}} cos(\omega_0 t)$ propagates. Now if $\mathcal {\hat {E}}$ is not constant but is a slowly varying function relative to the carrier frequency $\omega_0$, that is $\vert \frac{1}{\mathcal {\hat {E}}}\frac{d\mathcal {\hat {E}}}{dt}\vert << \omega_0$, then there will be a *low* frequency content created by the *non-linear* medium and whose bandwidth is of the order of twice that of $\mathcal {\hat {E}(t)}$. This is not the result of the sum frequency terms but rather of the *difference* frequency terms. For example, if $E(t)$ is the sum of two tones such as ${\hat {E}_0} cos(\omega_1 t) +{\hat {E}_0} cos(\omega_2 t)$ that low frequency term is proportional to $\chi^{(2)}\mathcal {\hat E}_0^2 cos((\omega_1-\omega_2)t)$.